# why does the logo in my universal header appear broken in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

As a Rails newbie, I am running into an issue in which I am struggling to figure out.

Im rendering a header universally across the four pages of my application which consists of home, about, (signup and signin which are administered through devise).

The header is fine across the home and about pages, however in the devise pages the logo image specifically arrives broken yet all of the other elements appear in tact. Any help would be appreciated.

> application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>SampleApp</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => false %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => false %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= yield :head %>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,700|Lobster' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>

    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="container">
    <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
     <%= content_tag(:div, msg, class: "alert alert-#{name}") %>
    <% end %>
    <%= yield %>
    </div>
  <%= render "layouts/footer" %>

</body>
</html>
```

> _header.html.erb

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-static-top navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
      <img alt="Nippon Beauty" class="navbar-brand-icon" src="assets/nippon.svg"><span class="logo-tagline">.CO.UK</span>
    </a> 
  </div>

      <input type="text" class="searchTerm" placeholder="What type of Skincare product would you like?">

  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "About", about_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Login", new_user_session_path %></li> 
      <li><%= link_to "Signup", new_user_registration_path %></li>
      <% if user_signed_in? %>
        <li><%= link_to "Account Settings", edit_user_registration_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
      <% else %>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

[image: HEADER]

[image: DEVISE HEADER RENDER]

Comment: Please add the contents of `layouts/header` file. I guess the problem is with your logo path.

Comment: is this to do with being a partial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the problem with how you set the path to your logo. Making it absolute or better use [`image_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag).

```
<img src="/assets/nippon.svg" ...
```

Notice, I've added `/` (forward slash) before `assets`.

**A better way of doing it would be:**

```
<%= image_tag('nippon.svg', alt: "Nippon Beauty", class: "navbar-brand-icon") %>
```

Comment: really appreciate the steering. thanks for taking the time.